# Create waffle chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle-chart

I'm trying to create a graph like this:

[image: Plot of filled stacked squares]

in `ggplot2`.

The idea is to visualize the distribution of True/False values, i.e. in the upper bar 3 out of 80 and in the lower bar 2 out of 280.
How would one do this in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`waffle` package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle).

```
library(waffle)

parts <- c('TRUE' = 3, 'FALSE' = 77)
p <- waffle(parts, rows = 8, colors = c("black", "grey70"))
p
```

[image]

```
class(p)
#[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

---

This is how you could combine two charts like in the graph above

```
iron(
  waffle(
    c('TRUE' = 3, 'FALSE' = 77),
    colors = c("black", "grey70"),
    size = 0.5,
    pad = 20,
    legend_pos = "none"
  ),
  waffle(
    c('TRUE' = 2, 'FALSE' = 278),
    colors = c("black", "grey70"),
    size = 0.5,
    legend_pos = "bottom"
  )
)
```

[image]