# In search of a Waffle-type chart for ordered binary data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have 3000-element vector populated with mostly zeros (0) and intermixed values of one (1) throughout.  I am attempting to visualize the degree of where the ones appear and their degree of sequential runs in the data.

I like the idea of a waffle chart with tiny squares with different colors denoting instances of 0 and 1.  Is there a means to tweak a waffle chart to achieve this 2-colored, ordered data, stacked representation?

The code below provides a 200-element vector populated with mostly zeros as an example.  A waffle-type chart with width = 20 and height = 10 is something along the lines of what I seek.

This solution is close to what I desire, except I need to retain the original order of the data in the visual.

[Create waffle chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997291/create-waffle-chart-in-ggplot2)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(waffle)

dabble <- ifelse(runif(200) < 0.8, 0, 1 )
dabble

# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
# [70] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
# [139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in ggplot directly using `geom_tile` and a little data shaping:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dabble <- ifelse(runif(200) < 0.8, 0, 1 )

df <- data.frame(z = dabble, x = rep(1:20, 10), y = rep(10:1, each = 20))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = factor(z))) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "red4"), name = NULL) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You're the man, Allan!  Add one more check mark to your 91,000 points.  Thank you.

Comment: One tiny follow-up question ... Is this type chart possible when the data are not exactly rectangular such as 199 points instead of 200?

Comment: @123blee yes, but you would want to pad the vector out until it is as large as the rectangle shape that would contain it with, say, the number 2. So if you had 199 values, do `vec <- c(vec, 2)`. Then set white as a third fill color.

Comment: Beautiful !  Thank you Allan.